# index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Tags: python, indexoutofboundsexception

```
N=100
numbers_training_pattern=10
for pattern in range(number_training_pattern):
rate=np.zeros((1,N))


   for epoch in range(1,nepochs+1):


        if epoch<=1:
           clamp=1
        else:
           clamp=0

       activ=np.zeros((1,N))
       for neuron in range(N):


          PreSynInput = rate.T + (Testing_pattern[neuron, pattern] * clamp)


          activ[neuron] = np.dot(PreSynInput.T,autocorrelation_matrix[:,neuron])
```

error
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
     17 
     18 
---> 19    activ[neuron] = np.dot(PreSynInput.T,autocorrelation_matrix[:,neuron])
     20 
     21

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Comment: You should refine your question to follow some of stackoverflow's guidelines. You have no clear question, no explanation whatsoever. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
activ=np.zeros((1,N))
```

means that `activ` has 1 row and `N` columns. `activ[0]` refers to the first row. `activ[1]` would raise an IndexError because there is no second row.

`for i in range(N)` makes `i` range from 0 to `N-1`. Hence, an error occurs if `N` is greater than 1.

One way to fix the error while changing the least amount of your current code would be to use

```
activ[0, neuron] = np.dot(PreSynInput.T,autocorrelation_matrix[:,neuron])
```

---

However, assigning values to a NumPy array element-by-element is usually not the ideal way to take advantage of NumPy. You'll get much better performance if you can express the computation as one done on larger arrays and without the Python for-loops.

For example, If I understand the shapes of the undefined arrays correctly, you
could replace

```
activ=np.zeros((1,N))
for neuron in range(N):
    PreSynInput = rate.T + (Testing_pattern[neuron, pattern] * clamp)
    activ[neuron] = np.dot(PreSynInput.T,autocorrelation_matrix[:,neuron])
```

with

```
PreSynInput = (rate.T + (Testing_pattern[:, pattern] * clamp))
activ = np.einsum('ij,ij->j', PreSynInput, autocorrelation_matrix)
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2015)
N, M, pattern = 10, 5, 0
clamp = 1
autocorrelation_matrix = np.random.randint(10, size=(N, N))
Testing_pattern = np.random.randint(10, size=(N, M))
rate = np.random.randint(10, size=(1,N))

activ=np.zeros((1,N))
for neuron in range(N):
    PreSynInput = rate.T + (Testing_pattern[neuron, pattern] * clamp)
    activ[:, neuron] = np.dot(PreSynInput.T, autocorrelation_matrix[:,neuron])

PreSynInput = (rate.T + (Testing_pattern[:, pattern] * clamp))
activ2 = np.einsum('ij,ij->j', PreSynInput, autocorrelation_matrix)

print(activ)
# [[ 405.  421.  272.  475.  227.  424.  644.  212.  325.  502.]]

print(activ2)
# [405 421 272 475 227 424 644 212 325 502]
```

---

You would get even better performance if you can find a way to eliminate the
`for pattern`-loop and `for epoch`-loop.

How to eliminate those loops is a problem sufficiently difficult and interesting
to justify a separate question. If you do post a new question about it, please include a [minimal example with runnable code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it
is absolutely clear what the desired output is for the given input.